# How do I take a berry off of a Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I've just started Alpha Sapphire,  and I've caught a Wurmple with a Pecha berry!

That Wurmple is not as good as the one I've caught earlier,  so I wanted to put the berry in my bag,  and some how discard that Wurmple. I can see how to move items around, but no way to just claim the berry back.

I've looked in the Pokémon and the item screen and nothing looks like it'd work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Pokémon menu, select the Wurmple, then select the Item option.